# I get type error if I execute the below code, and the error is TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

Here is my challenge:

> Write a program to find out the prime factors of a number. Example: prime factors of 56 - 2, 2, 2, 7

Here is my code:

```
num = 64
def factors (n):

    while n % 2 == 0:
        print(2)
        n = n/2

    for i in range (3,n):      
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)
            n = n/i

    if n > 2:
        print(n)

factors (num)
```

Comment: You want to use integer division `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: `n = n/2` is a float - `range(3,n)` wants an integer. floats =! integers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\` you should use `\\` . `\` is floating point division or simply `division` and `\\` is integer division or termed as `floor division`.
[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)

```
3 / 2 = 1.5
3 // 2 = 1
```

hence your code would look like,

```
num = 64
def factors (n):

    while n % 2 == 0:
        print(2)
        n = n//2

    for i in range (3,n):      
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)
            n = n/i

    if n > 2:
        print(n)

factors (num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got this error because range object gets integers as parameters and using `n = n/2` will convert n to a float so as [Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille) says, replace `n = n/2` by `n = n//2`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (i.e., replace "/" with "//" to get an integer instead of a float)

```py
num = 64

def factors(n):
    while n % 2 == 0:
        print(2)
        n = n // 2  # -------> Do the integer Division.

    for i in range(3, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)
            n = n / i

    if n > 2:
        print(n)


factors(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer division is important, as mention by others, but the most important is that your algorithm cannot detect multiple factors > 2 correctly.

```
def factors (n):
    for i in range (2, n):
        while (n % i == 0):
            print(i)
            n //= i
```